Spark Thread Hangs While Unpersisting a DataFrame
I am using Spark version 3.5.0 in stand alone mode and am facing an issue where my job thread (e.g., "scala-execution-context-global-514") sometimes hangs indefinitely until the Promise associated with the Future breaks due to a timeout being reached.My Question is What could be causing the thread to hang indefinitely?
Steps I've Taken: I referred to some GC-related problems which suggest that thread hangs can occur due to Stop-the-World (STW) pauses. However, I am confident there is no STW issue in my case because the thread (scala-execution-context-global-514) was stopped by the scheduler thread after the Promise broke.
code-snippet:
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    try {
        // Read file from HDFS
        val filePath = "hdfs://path/to/file.txt"
        val df = SparkAppUtil.sparkContext.read.option("header", "true").csv(filePath)
        returnDF = preActions(df) // Perform some pre-actions like parsing, cleaning, etc.

        // Persist the DataFrame
        transforms.zipWithIndex.foreach { case (eachTransform, idx) =>
            returnDF = applyTransform(eachTransform)
            if (idx % 15 == 0) {
                returnDF = SparkAppUtil.getCurrentJobContext.persistDataframe(returnDF)
                // This method will persist and store it in a list at thread-local.
            }
            // Perform some operation on returnDF and write DataFrames to HDFS
        }

        JobLogger.logInfo("Job Completed")

        // Unpersist all the DataFrames
        val persistedDataframes = SparkAppUtil.getCurrentJobContext.getPersistedDataframes
        for (df <- persistedDataframes) {
            df.unpersist()
            persistedDataframes -= df
        }
    } catch {
        case e: Exception =>
            JobLogger.logError("Error while processing: " + e.getMessage, e)
    } finally {
        if (SparkAppUtil.getCurrentJobContext.getPersistedDataframes.nonEmpty) {
            JobLogger.logInfo("Cleanup not completed!")
        }
    }
}

Debug Logs:
24/12/11 10:10:27 INFO JobLogger: Job Completed
24/12/11 10:10:27 INFO MapPartitionsRDD: Removing RDD 5571 from persistence list
24/12/11 10:10:27 DEBUG BlockManagerStorageEndpoint: removing RDD 5571
24/12/11 10:10:27 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 5571
24/12/11 10:10:27 DEBUG BlockManagerStorageEndpoint: Done removing RDD 5571, response is 0
24/12/11 10:10:27 DEBUG BlockManagerStorageEndpoint: Sent response: 0 to 172.xx.xx.xxx:34120
24/12/11 10:10:27 INFO MapPartitionsRDD: Removing RDD 5573 from persistence list
24/12/11 10:10:27 DEBUG BlockManagerStorageEndpoint: removing RDD 5573
24/12/11 10:10:27 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 5573
24/12/11 12:10:27 ERROR JobLogger: Error while processing :: 
java.lang.ThreadDeath
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:937)
    at com.etl.load.engine.spark.util.Interrupt.apply$mcZ$sp(Interrupt.scala:35)
    at com.etl.load.engine.spark.util.Interrupt.apply(Interrupt.scala:23)
    at com.etl.load.engine.spark.EventProcessor$.$anonfun$submitJob$2(EventProcessor.scala:157)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1426)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
null
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1367)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryAwait(Promise.scala:248)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:258)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkThreadUtils$.awaitResult(SparkThreadUtils.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askSync(RpcEndpointRef.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askSync(RpcEndpointRef.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMaster.removeRdd(BlockManagerMaster.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.unpersistRDD(SparkContext.scala:2075)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.unpersist(RDD.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.CachedRDDBuilder.clearCache(InMemoryRelation.scala:235)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CacheManager.$anonfun$uncacheQuery$6(CacheManager.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CacheManager.$anonfun$uncacheQuery$6$adapted(CacheManager.scala:218)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CacheManager.uncacheQuery(CacheManager.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CacheManager.uncacheQuery(CacheManager.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.unpersist(Dataset.scala:3834)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.unpersist(Dataset.scala:3845)
    at com.etl.load.engine.spark.context.JobContext.$anonfun$unpersistDataframes$1(JobContext.scala:642)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:38)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder.foreach$(TraversableForwarder.scala:38)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.foreach(ListBuffer.scala:47)
    at com.etl.load.engine.spark.context.JobContext.unpersistDataframes(JobContext.scala:641)
24/12/11 12:10:27 INFO JobLogger: Cleanup not completed!

Observations: Below is the stack trace of the Spark job thread at the point where it hangs. This was logged when the thread was interrupted:
java.lang.InterruptedException
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1367)
 at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryAwait(Promise.scala:248)
 at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:258)
 at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:263)
 at org.apache.spark.util.SparkThreadUtils$.awaitResult(SparkThreadUtils.scala:48)
 at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:310)
 at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
 at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askSync(RpcEndpointRef.scala:101)
 at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askSync(RpcEndpointRef.scala:85)
 at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMaster.removeRdd(BlockManagerMaster.scala:190)
 at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.unpersistRDD(SparkContext.scala:2075)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.unpersist(RDD.scala:213) 
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.CachedRDDBuilder.clearCache(InMemoryRelation.scala:235)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CacheManager.$anonfun$uncacheQuery$6(CacheManager.scala:218)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CacheManager.$anonfun$uncacheQuery$6$adapted(CacheManager.scala:218)
 at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
 at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
 at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
 at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
 at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
 at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CacheManager.uncacheQuery(CacheManager.scala:218)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CacheManager.uncacheQuery(CacheManager.scala:163)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.unpersist(Dataset.scala:3834)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.unpersist(Dataset.scala:3845)
 at com.etl.load.engine.spark.context.JobContext.$anonfun$unpersistDataframes$1(JobContext.scala:642)
 at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)
 at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:38)
 at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder.foreach$(TraversableForwarder.scala:38)
 at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.foreach(ListBuffer.scala:47)
 at com.etl.load.engine.spark.context.JobContext.unpersistDataframes(JobContext.scala:641)

Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated!
